# True or False? If $A \subset B \subset C \subset M$, where $A$ and $C$ are connected, then $B$ is connected.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, connectedness

> True or False? If $A \subset B \subset C \subset M$, where $A$ and $C$ are connected, then $B$ is connected.

I think it is false, but I can't think of a counter example.

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion? People will be more willing to answer your question if they can see you have put in some effort yourself first

Answer (score 4):

Take $A=(0,1), C=(0,2), B=(0,1) \cup \{1.5\}$

Answer (score 0):

Pick any non-connected set $B$. Can you think of a connected subset of $B$? A connected superset of $B$?